# RabbitMQ.Client BasicPublish returns before its complete

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I've got an issue where I have a console app that runs as a scheduled task and sends about 350k messages to the rabbit queue, disposes of the queue and ends. My problem is that the model.BasicPublish is returning before the message is actually completely published and when model.Close is called it ends up timing out. Another thing I've noticed is that after the application ends and is closed, the Rabbit Management UI says the exchange is still receiving messages for about 30-45 seconds. I am using the RabbitMQ.Client nugget package version 5.1.0

The code is pretty simple and a copy/paste (except for username/password):

```
        var connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.HostName = "localhost";
        connectionFactory.Password = "pass";
        connectionFactory.UserName = "user";
        connectionFactory.VirtualHost = "test";

        var connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
        var model = connection.CreateModel();

        model.QueuePurge("x");

        var fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"bigfile.txt");
        var accounts = fileLines.Select(x => x.Split(',').FirstOrDefault()).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x));
        var watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Start: " + DateTime.Now);
        foreach (var account in accounts)
        {
            var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(account);
            model.BasicPublish("incoming", "", null, bytes);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done: " + DateTime.Now);
        Console.WriteLine("Time: " + watch.Elapsed);
        try
        {
            model.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + exception);
        }
```

My rabbit config for the queue and exchange:

```
{
    "rabbit_version": "3.7.7",
    "policies": [],
    "queues": [
        {
            "name": "x",
            "durable": false,
            "auto_delete": false,
            "arguments": {}
        }
    ],
    "exchanges": [
        {
            "name": "incoming",
            "type": "direct",
            "durable": false,
            "auto_delete": false,
            "internal": false,
            "arguments": {}
        }
    ],
    "bindings": [
        {
            "source": "incoming",
            "destination": "x",
            "destination_type": "queue",
            "routing_key": "",
            "arguments": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

The foreach block takes about 14 seconds.

Does anybody have any idea on how to get this to work correctly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My understanding is that `IModel.BasicPublish` is supposed to be asynchronous like that. It returns as soon as it can after being called, and actually transmits the data on a background thread.

Comment: I think you want [publisher confirms](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html) turned on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the Rabbit Management UI says the exchange is still receiving messages
> for about 30-45 seconds

That is due to network data buffering.

> My problem is that the model.BasicPublish is returning before the
> message is actually completely published and when model.Close is
> called it ends up timing out

In this case, you should enable publisher confirms (via `ConfirmSelect` and `WaitForConfirms`) and only close the model once all published messages have been confirmed.

Comment: The ConfirmSelect and WaitForConfirms was the key to sending me down a better approach. It turns out that you can not use publisher confirms when doing the TxSelect/TxCommit/TxRollback, which I know isn't a real transaction, but better than nothing, so I ended up sending smaller batches and using the Tx* methods which also solved the problem.